# How to retrieve data from Database when I have option of 4 parameters using Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a Database of 10 Columns,
let it be like `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J`

Now if i want to extract data with a mix of 4 options
i.e say `B,C,H,J` (B is my primary key)
and none of them are mandatory to give data in the option.
say
Case 1 : `B,C,H` is given as parameters and `J` is given null

for all such cases I have to make a nested if Else statement ?

Because it will go for `4! (factorial)= 24 cases`

Is there any easy option for this???

Comment: Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) would be the usual place to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to do this using dynamic SQL but I’d also strongly recommend you read the article Mitch and Demien shared.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SearchProc
(
@param1 datetime,
@param2 int,
@param3 nvarchar
)
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @parameters nvarchar(300)

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE (1=1) '

if @param1 is not null
SET @sql = @sql + ' AND TableName.Column1 = @param1'

if @param2 is not null
SET @sql = @sql + ' AND TableName.Column2 = @param2'

if @param3 is not null
SET @sql = @sql + ' AND TableName.Column3 = @param3'

SET @parameters = '@param1 datetime, @param2 int, @param3 nvarchar'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @parameters, @param1, @param2, @param3

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. One option (but with caveats):

```
   WHERE
       (@paramA IS NULL OR Some Condition involving @paramA) AND
       (@paramB IS NULL OR Some Condition involving @paramB) AND
        ....
       (@paramH IS NULL OR Some Condition involving @paramH)
```

The caveat being this might make your stored procedure sensitive to parameter sniffing and cached query plans that are not appropriate for particular sets of parameters.

Another option is to construct dynamic TSQL.

As pointed out by @ Damien_The_Unbeliever: Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) is a great place to start.